# How to apply dotPlot(seqinr) function to every possible pairwise combination in vector containing protein sequences

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, plot, character

I'm R newbie and i would really appreciate some help.
I want to apply dotPlot(seqinr) function to every combination of two protein sequences from a vector containing 3 protein sequences. This means i want to get 3 dotPlot charts in the end.
I tried to use for loop:

```
#this is the vector containing 3 protein sequences. I turned each sequence to string to get 3 character vector:                      
seqs<-c(c2s(lepraeseq),c2s(ulceransseq),c2s(protseq))

#the loop:
for(i in 1:(length(seqs)-1)){
for(j in (i+1):length(seqs)){
print(dotPlot(as.character(i),as.character(j)))}}

#the outcome:
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

[the plot is empty and without the protein names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxn1M.png)

Clearly its wrong and i'm struggling to find the right way. 
i and j are integers and i want them to be vectors containing the sequences as characters and i just can't figure out how.

If someone have other way i would be glad to receive it.
Thank's,
Bella

Comment: Your question is not reproducible [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). We can't see the data in seqs. Also, specify from which package is `dotPlot`

Comment: thank's for the response. i wrote in the title that dotPlot function is from seqinr package. the data is 3 protein sequences which i downloaded from uniprot in fasta format. each sequence is a vector of characters: 'library("seqinr")
 leprae <- read.fasta(file = "C:/Users/Bella/Desktop/R/fasta/Q9CD83.fasta")
 ulcerans <- read.fasta(file = "C:/Users/Bella/Desktop/R/fasta/A0PQ23.fasta")
 prot<-read.fasta(file = "C:/Users/Bella/Desktop/R/fasta/Q32486.fasta")
 lepraeseq <- leprae[[1]]  '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to the data in lepraeseq, ulceransseq, etc. but this should work. You need to create an index object with all possible combinations using `combn`.

Using this index, you can then generate your plots in a loop. I see you're on windows. I added a line to save your plots on your drive.

```
library(seqinr)
seqs<-c("lepraeseq","ulceransseq","protseq")

comb <-combn(length(seqs),2) #get all possible pairwise combinations

for (i in 1:ncol(comb)){
dotPlot(s2c(seqs[comb[1,i]]),s2c(seqs[comb[2,i]]),
 xlab=seqs[comb[1,i]],ylab=seqs[comb[2,i]])
savePlot(filename = paste0("c:/temp/",paste0(seqs[comb[1,i]],"-",seqs[comb[2,i]]),".png"), 
 type ="png")
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, it worked but i still have problem with the names of the axes:                      `xlab=sequence[comb[1,i]],ylab=sequence[comb[2,i]`] `                               this script doesn't give the protein names but the protein sequence. I tried creating data frame with two columns: seq_name & sequence and to use it in the script above this way:      ` comb combn(length(df$sequence),2)for (i in 1:ncol(comb)){
  dotPlot(s2c(df$sequence[comb[1,i]]),s2c(df$sequence[comb[2,i]]),
          xlab=df$seq_name[comb[1,i]],ylab=df$seq_name[comb[2,i]])
}  `     **but it doesn't work**.

Comment: i succeed to get names:    `combSeq <-combn(length(sequence),2) #get all possible pairwise combinations
combName<-combn(length(seq_name),2)

for (i in 1:ncol(combSeq)){
  dotPlot(s2c(sequence[combSeq[1,i]]),s2c(sequence[combSeq[2,i]]),
          xlab=seq_name[combName[1,i]],ylab=seq_name[combName[2,i]])`